# How to Only install php5-mysql

Tags: debian, php5

Server System:Debian 7

My MySQL Server is not the same one for Apache Server,SO ,i want to install php5-mysql to connect mysql ,but when i use `apt-get install php5-mysql`,it always install mysql and mysql server automatic.
So, how to only install php5-mysql?

Maybe php5-mysql require other software package,could force only install php5-mysql,it maybe not run normaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apt-get` will install required dependancies, without which the package won't work correctly.

I doubt that an actual MySQL server gets installed as a dependancy but you will need additional MySQL client libraries and settings for the PHP MySQL [`php5-mysql`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/php5-mysql) extension to work. (among others: `libmysqlclient18` and `mysql-common`)

The [recommended alternative package](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/php-mysqlnd/) is to use the PHP Native Driver for MySQL [`php5-mysqlnd`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/php5-mysqlnd) which for starters does not depend on libmysql and is also much more performant.